# Simple Error handling in windows phone sdk

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have created a simple app which will do some calcualtions when user input some values.The app is working properly but when user forget to input some values in a textbox and run the app; the app stops working and it hangs. I want to know is there any simple error handling script for windows phone sdk.

I have used this error handiling script before in visual basic and in their its work perfectely.

```
On Error GoTo error_handler

    Dim one,two ....

 //some codes
.
.
......

error_handler:

        Textblock1.Text = "Error"
```

I tried to use this above script in sdk but its showing this error

```
Requested operation is not available because the runtime library function 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.CreateProjectError' is not defined.
```

Comment: Are you writing in VB (as per the code snippet) or C# (as per the tag)?

Comment: @zombiesheep The VB code given in the question is a script i used before for creating a desktop application. currently for mobile sdk i am using C#. I experimentely added VB code in C# sdk (as i am new to c#)and i got the above error

Answer (score 0):

As i asked in the question i was looking for a simple error handling script. I have found "accidently" the error handling script using try and catch method.Below is the code i used for error handiling.

```
Try

// Your code for app

Catch ex As Exception

MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK)

End Try
```